# Sort cells vertikaly connected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with data. From this data, the data from the sheet is transferred to a different sheet depending on the criteria. Here's an example. All information is entered on sheet 1. On sheet 2, depending on the entry in column I of sheet 1, the data are transferred.

I use the following to copy the data `=FILTER(Bestellungen!C:J; Bestellungen!I:I="H1")`

On the first sheet the date is also entered but not in order. Now I would like to copy on sheet 2 that yes all copied the sheet by date. I used the following script.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */  
function sortResponses() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Halle 1");  
  sheet.sort(1, false);   
}
```

But when I start it comes the following error:

Areas with vertically connected cells cannot be sorted. the cells in the range i1:i2 are connected vertically

Anybody any Idea?

Comment: /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function sortResponses() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Halle 1");
  sheet.sort(1, false);
}

Comment: Hi. My guess is that you have cells "i1:i2" are merged.

Comment: I unmeged it but it moves now the hole sheet and nothing is coipied now. Anyway i let it as be.

Comment: Merged cells are always a problem when generating ranges. Anyway, it looks as though your question has been answered.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a copy of your Sheet? This might be possible with Apps Script, or maybe copying the data in a hidden column and gather it from there. If you do, please make sure you don't share any private information.